# C# Array - Can't Get Values from DataLayer

Tags: c#

Need a little help on this one. I have been playing with this for a few days and I am having no luck. As you can see, I have tried a few different ways to return the results but I am not able to get the values.

I want to validate some results in the dataLayer but I am unable to return the the correct key/value. This seems to be an array within an array. I want to return the Key "NewPurchase" and if the value is a "Y" or "N" but for the life of me, I can't return that value.

What am I missing here?

```cs
public static string GetDataLayerValue()
{
    IJavaScriptExecutor js = _webDriver as IJavaScriptExecutor;
    object obj = js.ExecuteScript("return dataLayer;");
    IEnumerable<object> collection = (IEnumerable<object>)obj;
    int key = 0; // Set your initial key value here.
    var data = collection.ToDictionary(p => key++);

    //List<Object> obj1 = new List<Object>((IEnumerable<Object>)obj);

    foreach (var pair in data)
    {

        Console.WriteLine("FOREACH VAR: {0}, {1}", pair.Key, pair.Value);

        if (pair.Value.ToString() == "NewPurchase")
        {
                var t1 = pair.Key;
                var v1 = pair.Value.ToString();
                return v1;

        }
    }

    return "Not Found";
}
```

[image]

Comment: Is your if statement firing ? If yes the try just returing pair.Value.ToString()
also worth adding a Debug.WriteLine(pair.Key.ToString());
just to see if it is returning what you think it is

Comment: The way you construct data, it will be a `Dictionary<int, string>`, with key being 0, 1, 2, .... So how can `pair.Key` ever be "NewPurchase"? Why don't you just iterate over `collection`?

Comment: Yup `pair.Key.ToString()` will never equal `"NewPurchase"`

Comment: There's a pattern we generally avoid: `int key = 0; var data = collection.ToDictionary(p => key++);` instead you'd perhaps do `collection.Select((item, idx) => new { I = item, X = idx }).ToDictionary(at => at.X, at => at.I)`

Comment: Everyone -  thanks for your help. I have been playing with this for far too long and I am still not able to get the value I need. <bangs head on wall>  Maybe I have just been looking at this too long but I can't get my brain wrapped around it. I will keep looking but again, thanks for the help.

Comment: oh I see what you were sating about pair.key == NewPurchase. That got changed a long the way. I had been looking at the value not the key. Updated above.